# Посоветуйте хороший справочник по Android программированию

Tags: java, android, книги, справка

Мне нужен не учебник, а именно справочник, чтобы можно было изучить конкретную, нужную мне в данный момент, тему, без необходимости чтения десяти предшествующих глав.

Comment: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/ - Есть вот такой сайт. Там далеко не всем советам стоит следовать, но, когда я начинал, много полезного в доступной форме нашел. Как справочник - лучшее после SO и документации на мой взгляд)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/docs?hl=RU